# niftymbaasからmonacaアプリにリンク先へ飛ばせるデータを送りたい。

Tags: javascript, monaca, html

niftymbaasとmonacaを使用してアプリの作成を行っています。
niftymbaas側からリンク(http://×××.com)をmonacaアプリ側に表示させリンク先へ飛ばせるようにしたいと考えております。
基本的にniftymbaas側からアプリ側にリンクを送ることはできるのでしょうか？
できるのであればどなたかご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

プッシュ通知を利用する方法があります。
mbaasではプッシュ通知に付随してJSON形式のデータを渡すことができるので、これを利用してサーバからURLを渡し、アプリ側でこのJSONデータを加工してリンクを生成するという方法です。

下記ページ等をお読みになると良いと思います。
http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/push/basic_usage_monaca.html

ややぼんやりした回答になりましたが、できるかできないかで言えば確実にできますので、上記等を参考にまずは試行錯誤してみてください。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。
とても参考になりました、試行錯誤してみます。
ありがとうございました。